# Jquery toggle list elements by inner element's texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I cannot find out why my filter function does not work for toggling on `li` elements.

---

### JavaScript:

```
$("#searchbox1").on("keyup", function() {
   var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   $("#menulist li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).children("span").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
   });
});
```

---

### HTML:

```
<ul name="menulist" id="menulist" class="list-group grid-container">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <span>Yeni ürün ekle</span>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm ml-auto" role="group">

            <a class="btn btn-success" href="/restaurant/additem">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </a>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li name="bira" class="list-group-item d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <span>bira</span>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm ml-auto" role="group">
            <a href="/restaurant/edititem/-10" class="btn btn-success"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></a>
            <a href="/restaurant/delete/-10" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li name="patates kızartması" class="list-group-item d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <span>patates kızartması</span>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm ml-auto" role="group">
            <a href="/restaurant/edititem/-11" class="btn btn-success"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></a>
            <a href="/restaurant/delete/-11" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

### Desired effect:

I just want a simple search box effect but the list items are not going anywhere. When I play with code like this:

```
$("#menulist span").filter(...)
```

I can see all `span` elements toggling according to the search value, but I want to hide the `li` elements, **that don't match with the search value**. I am missing something, but what?

Comment: Do `$(this).parent().toggle(...);` rather than `$(this).toggle(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filtering code is actually spot on! So there's no need to change any JavaScript.

---

### So what's the issue?

Your `li` elements all have the Bootstrap 4 class `d-flex`. This is an issue because when filtering through the list, it will give the elements that don't match the CSS `display: none;`. However this cannot be applied due to `d-flex` being an `!important` value. Which means whenever your code tries to set your `li`'s to be `display: none`, it will be overriden by the `display: flex !important` property that `d-flex` adds.

---

### So how do I fix this?

By removing the `d-flex` class from all of your `li` elements and instead setting them to be `display: flex;` with some custom CSS.

```
.list-group-item {
  display: flex;
}
```

---

### Example:

See the fixed version on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rexku1q9/6/).

Comment: Thank you for interest. After doing so ,now , the function only checks for last list item .If it matches , it does not hide others whole <ul> stays there.If i search for other  <li> elements, it hides whole list.

Comment: I guess you guys misunderstood my  ""But of course I just want to hide list elements as a whole.""" word.I was comparing the example i gave with span.I don't meant to hide whole list, just unmatched ones. I am editing the question now.

Comment: You are the real mvp.Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)